# Error referencing node modules when starting a nodejs server in c# using edge.js

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js

I am trying to have my nodejs server run on start up of my Windows Forms application using Edgejs. I am encountering a hiccup when referencing my api module. Is this an error within EdgeJS that I cannot control and need to find a way around? What if I made an API controller instead? NOTE: When using this same exact code in my web application it functions as expected.

c# start up file

```
public static async void Start()
{

    var createHttpServer = Edge.Func(File.ReadAllText("../../../../server/server.js"));


    await createHttpServer(new
    {
        port = 3333,
    });


}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run((Action)Start).Wait();
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

server.js

```
"use strict";

var http = require('http');
var express    = require('express');                    // web framework
var cors       = require('cors');                       // middleware for express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');                // parsing module
var path       = require('path');
var edge       = require('edge');
var api = require('./api.js');


return function (options, cb) {
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': 'true'}));   // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/api/getFullCatalog', api.getFullCatalog());

// IMPORTANT!: This rule has to be last rule for routing as it has very common definition
app.all('/*', function (request, response) {
    var fileName, serverPath;
    console.log('Send: ' + __dirname + request.url);
    serverPath = path.resolve(__dirname + '../../../../../../server/');
    fileName = serverPath + request.url;

    response.sendFile(fileName);
});

// start server listening on defined port
app.listen(options.port);
console.log('The NodeJS server is ready.');
};
```

I can start the server and run when I remove said module

```
var api = require('./api');
```

Here is the error

```
{"Error: Cannot find module './api.js'\n    
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)\n    
at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)\n    
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)\n    
at require (module.js:384:17)\n    
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\\TechSpikeUDC\\TechSpikeUDC\\WpfApplication1\\bin\\x86\\Debug\\edge\\double_edge.js:34:28), <anonymous>:9:11)\n    
at compileFunc (C:\\TechSpikeUDC\\TechSpikeUDC\\WpfApplication1\\bin\\x86\\Debug\\edge\\double_edge.js:35:16)"}
(C:\\TechSpikeUDC\\TechSpikeUDC\\TechSpikeUDC\\bin\\x86\\Debug\\edge\\double_edge.js:34:28), <anonymous>:37:15)"}   System.Exception
```

Again this only happens when used in the thick client c# application.

Any help is appreciated... Thank you.